# JSF 2 Custom components having Expression Language for attribute value don't trigger the attribute setter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, attributes, custom-component

I have build a custom component in JSF 2.0

The tag looks like this:

```
<x:myTag id="1" name="AAA" />
```

The corresponding java class:

```
@FacesComponent("a.b.c.MyTag")
public class UIMyTag extends UIInput {

   private String name;
   private String id;

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }


   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
       ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
       logger.debug(getName()); //prints null for name="#{dummyBean.name}" 
                                //   and AAA for name="AAA"
       logger.debug(getAttributes().get("name")); // always correct value
   ...
}
   ....

}
```

If I use

```
<x:myTag id="1" name="AAA" />
```

everything works as expected, but when I use EL for myTag attributes the `setName()` method never gets called. So for,

```
<x:myTag id="#{dummyBean.id}" name="#{dummyBean.name}" />
```

I always get `null` for the `name` property inside my `encodeBegin` method. After debugging I've noticed that the `setName` method never gets called. I thought that maybe something regarding EL messes things up (and I still believe that the reason is related to that), but what's really weird is that the `id` property works good: the setter gets called, and the value is as expected when the econding begins.

I have to mention that if I call `getAttributes().get("name")` from the `encodeBegin` method I get the correct name value, but I'm intrigued why it doesn't work with getter and setter.

Any ideas what's missing to my component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is expected and by specification. Attribute values which are value expressions are set by [`UIComponent#setValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression%28java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression%29). They are namely supposed to be evaluated only when they are *really* been used, usually during view render time.

The `id` (and `binding`) attribute has special treatment: it's evaluated during view build time *before* it's been set, so the "regular" setter would be called instead of the `setValueExpression()` (because rendering of the view would otherwise crash when the `id` (or `binding`) attribute dynamically evaluates to a different value than it was during the view build time for some reason).

Better is to delegate the getters/setters to [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper%28%29) instead of to local properties. The `setValueExpression()` ultimately also end up in the `StateHelper` (note that it doesn't call the setter at all; just call the getter if you need the data) and the `getAttributes()` also resolves the values from the `StateHelper`.

```
public String getName() {
   return (String) getStateHelper().eval("name");
}

public void setName(String name) {
    getStateHelper().put("name", name);
}
```

Note that you can safely *remove* the `getId()` and `setId()` methods, because they're already definied in the `UIComponentBase` superclass which you're extending from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to ask if I have to implement some special method to distinguish between different types of attributes values inside my component. (I understood that UIComponentBase handles it on its own) And if yes, is there a best practice to do it?!

Comment: No and you should generally not care about it either. To get the (evaluated) attribute value, just invoke the getter.