# JSF component created in encodeBegin not visible in decode

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primefaces commandButton in custom component action listener not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176501/primefaces-commandbutton-in-custom-component-action-listener-not-called)

I have created custom component which extends `UIComponentBase`. I am creating
some component in `encodeBegin` (`CommandButton` from Primefaces), but when
is `decode` triggered by user clicking button when I look for button it is not
present in `UIViewRoot` and not in `this.getChildren()`.

It seems that it is a new instance of component invoked when `decode` is trigered and components are not present.
What is wrong?

Some code is in:
[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176501/primefaces-commandbutton-in-custom-component-action-listener-not-called)

If you want I can send whole code.

---

I found that this technique is used in PrimeFaces and other software, but can you explain why values retrieved from getStateHelper().eval("someKey"); are always null in decode?

Probably problem on my site, but I can not solve it?

This is link to thread I started:

[problem description in more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176501/primefaces-commandbutton-in-custom-component-action-listener-not-called)

Answer (score 1):

> *It seems that it is a new instance of component invoked when decode is trigered and components are not present.*

That's correct. Component instances are not stored in the view state. Instead, the component's state is stored in the view state. The component's state can be managed by the helper class [`StateHelper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHelper.html) which is available by [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper%28%29).

So, during encode do:

```
// ...
getStateHelper().put("someKey", someKey);
```

And during decode do:

```
SomeKey someKey = (SomeKey) getStateHelper().eval("someKey");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How to save state when extending UIComponentBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405278/how-to-save-state-when-extending-uicomponentbase)
- [JSF composite component - weird behavior when trying to save state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015942/jsf-composite-component-weird-behavior-when-trying-to-save-state)
- [JSF 2 Custom components having Expression Language for attribute value don't trigger the attribute setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866981/jsf-2-custom-components-having-expression-language-for-attribute-value-dont-tri)

Comment: Can you explain why values retrieve from getStateHelper().eval("someKey"); are always null in decode?

Comment: This should not happen. Is the component declared in the view or are you manually creating it? The latter would explain it.

Comment: I am creating it manually in my custom component.

Comment: You should not manually create the custom component. The custom component should be created by the view.

Comment: I have it in my site: <i:categoriesTag idSuffix="cats-list" categories="#{categoryController.categories}"></i:categoriesTag> and inside of this component I am creating commandButton

Comment: Well, if you're using `StateHelper#put()` in encode, then it should definitely be able by `StateHelper#eval()` or `get()` in decode of the postback. If it isn't, then perhaps you're not performing a postback.